# Redirect stderr to logger and then to file

Tags: linux, bash, logging, stderr

I'm trying to take `stderr` from a command and redirect it to the `logger -s` command (which writes its input to `syslog` and the `-s` option sends a copy of the input to `logger`'s standard error) and then finally to a file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

ping foobar 2> logger -s 2>> ~/mylog.log
```

Unfortunately, this creates a `logger` file and a `mylog.log` file.  So I'm assuming the initial `2>` creates a `logger` file and then the `2>>` creates a new `mylog.log` file.

Is there anyway to redirect `stderr` to the `logger` command?

**EDIT**

I'm trying to avoid using `|` because I want to use the redirection in `if` tests as well.

I also tried this way:

```
ping foobar 2> $(logger -s 2>> ~/mylog.log)
```

And that didn't work either.

Comment: Could you explain what if tests you're trying to do that don't work with a pipe?

Comment: Is `logger` a process or a file?  As written, the code creates an empty file `logger` for standard error to go to, then changes its mind and sends standard error so that it is appended to `mylog.log`.  Are you wanting the standard error sent to both files, one in append mode and one in plain write mode?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `logger` is a unix program I'm trying to use.  I'm unintentionally creating a logger file using redirection whereas I want to pass `stderr` to the logger unix program and redirect that to a file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the manual page for [logger](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_logger.htm), you were looking for `bash`'s [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) and:

```
ping foobar 2> >(logger -s 2>> ~/mylog.log)
```

This runs `ping foobar` with standard error going to the process `logger -s` via process substitution.  The `logger` process writes the information to `syslog` (the primary purpose of `logger`) and also writes the output to standard error (the `-s` option).  The second I/O redirection appends the standard error from `logger` to the file `~/mylog.log`.

The return status of the command is the return status from `ping`.  This avoids pipes, so you can use the command as written in `if` tests, etc.

Comment: But when I do this:  ls 2> >(logger "adsad") even if there is no ls error, my syslog contains "adsad" string.

Comment: @meso_2600: I think you will find that `logger` is supposed to do that.  If you ask it to write something, it will write it to `syslog`.  You can decide whether `logger` doesn't know whether it is an error and simply assumes that it is, or whether `logger` knows that it is an error because it was asked to write it -- the net result is the same.  When asked to write, `logger` writes.

Comment: ok so is there any way to have a one-liner that on stderr tells logger to write something?

Comment: what I meant is that in the syslog I want to have stderr only

Comment: The `2> >(logger -s 2>> ~/log/mylog.log)` notation ensures that `logger` writes the messages from its standard input (if any) to both `syslog` and to its standard error, which is here redirected to the log file.  If you provide an argument like `"adsad"` to `logger`, it writes that message to `syslog` and exits.  So, as long as you arrange for the standard error of some command to write to the standard input of `logger`, you will get to see the error messages (one line per message) in `syslog`, but only if there are messages to write.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want stderr...

```
ping foobar  3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | logger >> ~/mylog.log
```

This should swap sderr and stdout.

Answer (score 1):

You can't normally redirect to multiple files. That's what `tee` is for. Also, if you're gonna use `tee` you *need* to use a pipe.

```
ping foobar 2>&1 >/dev/null | tee -a ~/mylog.log | logger
```

This redirects stderr to stdout and then stdout to /dev/null. `tee` appends its input to file `~/mylog.log` (`-a` is for append) and also copies it to output, which is then piped to `logger`.

If you want to use any resulting complex command in an if test you can put the command in a function. You can use bash's `$PIPESTATUS` to check each exit status in the pipe (and return it from the function):

```
function bla {
    ping | successful_cmd   # ... or whatever
    [ 0 -eq ${PIPESTATUS[0]} ]   # return 0 (true) if the exit status of ping was 0 (true)
}
```

The return status of the function will be the the return status of the last command executed. You can use the function like this:

```
if bla; then echo true; else echo false; fi
# or
bla && echo success
```

Comment: if you were trying to test if the ping was a success or not, how would that work in an if test with the pipe?

Comment: Initially thought `logger` was a file you wanted to save the output to :D I edited the answer. Also added info about $PIPESTATUS.